# "java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400"

Tags: java

recibo esta excepción "java.io.IOException: el servidor devolvió el código de respuesta HTTP: 400" al obtener InputStream. No he podido conectarme al servidor, me arroja en ocasiones error 400 y cuando hago modificaciones me da un error 500. el asunto es que me dan una URL en la cual lleva una apikey por ejemplo  https://algoconstrudio/loginCajetin?apikey=qweertrtyu2134324, cuando realizo una consulta en postman me da una respuesta de un json el metodo utilizado para realizar la consulta es por POST pero ademas debo enviar por el body tres parametros obligatorios para poder acceder a la respuesta que emite, la pregunta es la siguiente como puedo enviar en Java usando HttpUrlConnection los tres parametros utilizados en el body en postman y recibir la respuesta, este es el código que tengo por los momentos:
** Necesito de su ayuda y colaboración ya llevo varios días intentando hacer esto pero he podido resolverlo y muchas gracias a todos aquellos que me brinden su ayuda y apoyo.

```
URL url = new URL("https://algoconstrudio/loginCajetin?apikey=qweertrtyu2134324");

String JSONSend = "{'client_secret':'1sd51awd5-65a4we5dd1-sa1d', 'client_id':'4s54sdawdawdw-aw5d451', 'type':'authorization'}";

byte[] postDataBytes = JSONSend.getBytes("utf-8");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("client_secret", "1sd51awd5-65a4we5dd1-sa1d");
conn.setRequestProperty("client_id","4s54sdawdawdw-aw5d451");
conn.setRequestProperty("type","authorization");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);


try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
  wr.write( postDataBytes );
  wr.flush();
  wr.close();
}
//conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);

Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
  sb.append((char)c);
String response = sb.toString();

//JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

String jsonResult =  (response);

return jsonResult;
```

Comment: No he revisado tu código a detalle, pero de sólo mirar la primera línea me doy cuenta que tu string `JSONSend` no es un `json` válido. El formato `json` no admite comillas simples, deben ser dobles. Por otro lado, si estás enviando un `json` ¿Por qué el `Content-Type` es `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` y no `application/json`? Por favor, revisa [este tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/httpurlconnection-post). [Así](https://pastebin.com/jNYwp9vL) debe lucir tu string. Si usas java moderno puedes usar la triple comilla para declarar el json """ tu json """, o mejor aún, una librería externa.

Comment: Si dices que en postman funciona, por favor, agrega la petición http que estás haciendo en postman para ver si coincide con la que estás haciendo en java. Para ello, simplemente ve al [botón que está en el menú lateral derecho](https://ibb.co/TqCBZpB) y exporta la petición que haces en postman a `Http` para ver cómo la haces. Copia el código de la petición en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

El JSON en tu código no es válido, se tiene que utilizar doble comilla. Veo también que el content type lo estás poniendo mal. Este sería mi código basado en tu ejemplo:

```
String JSONSend = "{\"client_secret\":\"1sd51awd5-65a4we5dd1-sa1d\", \"client_id\":\"4s54sdawdawdw-aw5d451\", \"type\":\"authorization\"}";

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);

try(OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
    byte[] input = JSONSend.getBytes("utf-8");
    os.write(input, 0, input.length);           
}
```

El código lo obtuve de [acá](https://www.baeldung.com/httpurlconnection-post)